# Grid bag layout struggles

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create the following GUI in Java Swing. After doing some research I found out The Grid Bag Layout was the most flexible and "best" manager to use. Problem is that I have some struggles with it and cannot really figure it out.

This is the layout I want to create:

[image]

It's really simple, but that's what I want. I want to start simple.

I started with title and just the first to buttons but this is what happened:

[image]

The Title is fine, but the buttons are stretched all the way out. Of course, this is because of: `gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`, but it want it to, but not all the way. maybe 1/6 of the frame.

Anyway, this is my code:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private XJLabel jlNaam, welcome;
    private XJTextField jtfNaam;
    private XJButton jbOk;
    private XJButton jbOk2;

    public MainFrame() {
        setTitle("TITLE");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        welcome = new XJLabel("TITLE!", 30);
        welcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        jbOk = new XJButton("ok");
        jbOk2 = new XJButton("ok2");

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.weightx = 3;
        panel.add(welcome, gc);

        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(jbOk, gc);

        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(jbOk2, gc);

        add(panel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The "X" Classes are nothing special, it's just there to make it a tiny bit nicer.

How might I achieve this? I am open to better ways to do this. Do note: I am in school thus not allowed to use third party Layout managers. So I have to get the hang of the default ones.

Comment: `weightx` and `weighty` probably aren't doing what you think

Comment: Yeah... Probably. Also tried `gridwidth`, but did not work aswell...

Comment: `The "X" Classes are nothing special,` - they should NOT be used in code you post in the forum. We don't have access to those classes and they are not relevant to your stated question. We should be able to execute the code you post.

Comment: @camickr Oh, Of course. You are right. Won't do it again in future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it looks like you want components in 3 columns.

Problem is in your case you don't have any single row that has 3 columns of components so you can't position the "Title" and bottom "Button" as you would like.

So if you want to use a GridBagLayout you will need to fake it. So in your second row you would need to add a dummy component in the 3rd columns. You should be able to use `Box.createHorizontalStrut(10)` and add it to the row in the 3rd column.

Now in the first row the component can be centered by giving it a `gridwidth = 3`

In the last row you add the button using a `gridx = 2`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The demo there does almost exactly what you want.

> I found out The Grid Bag Layout was the most flexible and "best" manager to use

However, you are never forced to use a single layout manager.

For example you could use a panel with a vertical `BoxLayout`. Then you would:

1. add the label to the panel.
2. add the button to the panel.
3. create a sccond panel using a left aligned `FlowLayout` and add the buttons to the buttons panel and the panel.
4. add `Box.createVerticalGlue()` to the panel.
5. add the last button to the panel.

Note:

1. You will need to use the `setAlignmentX(...)` method to properly align the components in the left/center/right locations.
2. For the buttons panels you will need to use `buttonsPanel.setMaximumSize( buttons.getPreferredSize() )` to prevent the panel from growing in height.

Try implement both solutions to better understand the concept of nesting layout managers. Then you can choose the option you prefer for future layouts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I have tried both options, but I think I like the grid bag layout a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

`GridBagLayout` is one of the most flexible layout managers, but it is also one of the most complicated.

A lot of the times, getting out some paper and drawing the layout will make it easier to understand how you want to apply the constraints.

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() throws HeadlessException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            // Fill the first row
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            JLabel title = new JLabel("Title!");
            title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(title, gbc);

            // First column, second row
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;

            add(makeLabel("Button"), gbc);

            // First column, second row
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(makeLabel("Button 2"), gbc);

            // Second column, second row
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(makeLabel("Button 3"), gbc);

            // Last column
            gbc.gridx++;
            // The the remaining area
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            // Bottom/right
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
            add(makeLabel("Button 4"), gbc);
        }

        protected JLabel makeLabel(String text) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            label.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is straight up use of `GridBagLayout`.  Depending on your needs, you might find it easier to use two or more compounding layouts instead

Comment: Okay wow, you live up to your name... ;) Thanks a lot! This really helps out a lot!